# How to marshal a large amount of data to XML

Tags: xml, go, marshalling

I need to send a large amount of data via XML and my Docker container runs out of memory when performing the task. Is there a way using Go to incrementally marshal a large XML document and also incrementally write it to a file so as to minimize memory usage?

Comment: How do you do it currently? Isn't `xml.Encoder()` suitable for you?

Comment: Right now, I gather all of the data that should go in the document (4+ GB), marshal it with `xml.Marshal` and then use `ioutil.WriteFile`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`xml.Encoder`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/#Encoder) to stream the XML output to an [`io.Writer`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Writer) that may be a network connection ([`net.Conn`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#Conn)) or a file ([`os.File`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#File)). The complete result will not be kept in memory.

You may use [`Encoder.Encode()`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/#Encoder.Encode) to encode a Go value to XML. Generally you may pass any Go value that you would pass to [`xml.Marshal()`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/#Marshal).

`Encoder.Encode()` only helps if the data you want to marshal is ready in-memory, which may or may not be feasible to you. E.g. if you want to marshal a large list which cannot (or should not) be read into memory, this will not be a salvation to you.

If the input data also cannot be held in memory, then you may construct the XML output by tokens and elements. You may use [`Encoder.EncodeToken()`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/#Encoder.EncodeToken) for this which allows you to write "parts" of the result XML document.

For example if you want to write a large list to the output, you may write a start element tag (e.g. `<list>`), then write the elements of the list one-by-one (each fetched from database or from file, or constructed by an algorithm on-the-fly), and once the list is marshaled, you may close the list element tag (`</list>`).

Here's a simple example how you can do that:

```
type Student struct {
    ID   int
    Name string
}

func main() {
    he := func(err error) {
        if err != nil {
            panic(err) // In your app, handle error properly
        }
    }

    // For demo purposes we use an in-memory buffer,
    // but this may be an os.File too.
    buf := &bytes.Buffer{}

    enc := xml.NewEncoder(buf)
    enc.Indent("", "  ")

    he(enc.EncodeToken(xml.StartElement{Name: xml.Name{Local: "list"}}))
    for i := 0; i < 3; i++ {
        // Here you can fetch / construct the records
        he(enc.Encode(Student{ID: i, Name: string(i + 'A')}))
    }
    he(enc.EncodeToken(xml.EndElement{Name: xml.Name{Local: "list"}}))
    he(enc.Flush())

    fmt.Println(buf.String())
}
```

Output of the above is (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/rllhbQyo4I7)):

```
<list>
  <Student>
    <ID>0</ID>
    <Name>A</Name>
  </Student>
  <Student>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <Name>B</Name>
  </Student>
  <Student>
    <ID>2</ID>
    <Name>C</Name>
  </Student>
</list>
```